# How to uninstall Linux from a MacBook properly?

Tags: macos, command-line, disk-utility, partition, unix

There are a lot of questions by those who have already bricked their macs trying to remove Linux so their questions usually stem from a position where one of the disk is labelled FFFF-FFFFFFFF-and more F's.
They come from the angle of having already done something wrong.

I'm not in that position, and I'd rather not start by bricking my mac.

Does you have any ideas on how to properly remove Linux from my mac (this includes the hidden FFFF partition)?

Any help explained in a very basic manner would be much appreciated.

`diskutil list` below

[image: <code>diskutil list</code>]

It may also be worth mentioning that in both
/dev/disk0 and /dev/disk1 there are gpt partitions when looked at via recovery mode.

to address the suspicious MBR sector I've used the command

```
sudo fdisk/dev/disk0
```

to give an inside look

[image]

Comment: Since you have the `Suspicious MBR at sector 0` message, you should include the output from `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`.

Comment: The output from `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` shows that you already have errors in the partition tables. Basically, you have incorrect hybrid partitioning. The answer will have to be modified to reflex this. Which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @klanomath I didn't delete the partition yet since that's the issue people normally come across, I was trying to avoid the whole FFFF-FFFF-etc and the /dev/disk1 can only be viewed in recovery mode where I cannot screenshot, but I can photograph it if you'd like.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Catalina. ver 10.15.2

Comment: Tried and tested, both `sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s(X)` commands **DO** work on Catalina

Comment: @DavidAnderson your answer is spot on, mucho appreciato my brother. Restarted my device with no issues whatsoever and avoided bricking my mac and having to deal with all the trouble that comes after that.

Comment: @klanomath I still appreciate your input as well.

Answer (score 4):

Evidently, the tricky part is the removal of the Linux partitions (`disk0s3` and `disk0s4`).

The last partition (`disk0s4`) is the Linux swap partition. The following command can be used to return this partition free space. This should also remove the hybrid partitioning in the Master Boot Record (MBR) Partition Table.

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s4
```

The command below should return the remaining Linux partition (`disk0s3`) to free space. However, when tested under High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6), this command **failed** to work properly.

> Note: When tested under Catalina (macOS 10.15.2), command below did work properly. However, after participating in discussions posted at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380892/how-can-i-properly-remove-linux-and-resize-the-partition-if-its-showing-fffffff), I can report the command may still fail under Catalina.

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

The alternative way to remove this partition is to boot to [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and use the command shown below. ***I would recommend using the command below over the above command.*** After entering the command below, you can boot back to macOS.

```
gpt -f remove -i 3 disk0
```

The next command returns the free space back to the APFS container (`disk0s2`).

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

The next command mounts the EFI volume (`disk0s1`).

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
```

The next command removes the linux boot files from the EFI volume. This will prevent Linux from appearing in the Startup Manager. With some versions of Linux, this folder may not exist.

```
rm -r /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT
```

There will be other boot files remaining in the EFI volume. You do not have to remove these files if you do not wish to. The files will be in a folder named after the Linux that was installed. For example, with Ubuntu the command would be as follows.

```
rm -r /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Ubuntu
```

The next command unmounts the EFI volume (`disk0s1`).

```
sudo diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

Comment: @klanomath: If the boot volume is APFS formatted, then High Sierra or newer version of macOS is being used. The `diskutil` command automatically converts hybrid partitioning back to pure GPT when used. This change in behavior of the `diskutil` command started with High Sierra. So, when `disk0s4` was removed, so was the hybrid partitioning.

Comment: Good to know... ;-)

Comment: @klanomath: The original `gpt` command required exclusive access to `disk0` before making a change. At least since High Sierra, the `-f` option was added which allows shared access. So you no longer need a `diskutil unmountDisk disk0` command to precede the use of a `gpt` command. This brought `gpt` inline with the abilities that `fdisk` and `gdisk` already had. In this case, removal of `disk0s3` by `gpt` should do no harm, since macOS normally does not mount Linux volumes.

Comment: Unmounting volumes and disks before issueing `gpt ...` commands became part of my flesh and blood so that I never realized/used the -f option...