# How can I properly remove Linux and resize the partition if it's showing FFFFFFFFFFFF-FFFFF-FFFFF without turning off my Macbook?

Tags: macos, command-line, disk-utility, partition, unix

Having deleted both linux partitions from my device using

`sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s4`

and

`sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3`
In an attempt to then have both partitions rejoin the larger one i used

`sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0`

but it was unsuccessful to my chagrin.

[image]

I checked my with `diskutil list`

and now I have a shady FFFF-FFFF-FFFF partition instead of the normal `disk0s2`.

[image]

How can I revert the partition to its normal state and resize the partition **without** turning off my macbook and messing up the entire thing.

This is on macOS catalina 10.15.2

I have also an image of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated **besides** saying just use a time machine.

`gpt -r show /dev/disk0`

[image]

**EDIT**

After implementing David Anderson's solution the end result was this

[image]

Which seems to have restored the partition to it's normal state.

Both of David Anderson's solutions work

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0 
Password:
disk0s2 removed
MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 1796865488 -t apfs disk0
disk0s2 added
```

Comment: How did the OP manage to enter the command `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` without getting the message `fdisk: /dev/disk0: Operation not permitted`? Either SIP is off or the computer is already booted to macOS Recovery. If so, then why not just use the `gpt` command to fix the problem?

Comment: No particular reason other that the strange feeling that I did something wrong because the partition disk0s2 isn't labelled as it normally should be @klanomath .
Do you believe that I can safely reboot my system even though the linux partitions are yet to rejoin the much larger disk0s2

Comment: Yes, SIP is disabled. @DavidAnderson , but what ``gpt`` command are you referring to? I tried to have to deleted space rejoin the original ``disk0s2`` but to no avail and that has me on edge a bit.

Comment: @ArtoriusCastus: The `gpt` command has occasionally come up with respect to the FFFF problem. [See here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFF-FFFF)

Comment: Are there any actions I can take to resolve this issue seeing as this is an strange boot scenario @klanomath. Do you suggest i just reboot anyways and see what happens?

Comment: steps for that if you don't mind @klanomath. I'd rather be sure of what I'm doing with some friendly input from you

Comment: Post the output from the command `sudo gdisk -r show /dev/disk0`.

Comment: ``MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo gdisk -r show /dev/disk0

Password:
sudo: gdisk: command not found``

Comment: just added an image for
``gpt -r show /dev/disk0``

Comment: Please do not post graphic images of Terminal output! Simply copy and paste the output and use code formatting so it displays properly.

Comment: @ArtoriusCastus You just have to c&p the Terminal window's content and hit {} in the edit window. The problem with screenshots: you can't copy text from it and have to type it instead. If I mistype the size of disk0s2 (1796865488), an answer containing the wrong size wouldn't work. c&p the size (or other data) from your question is faster, more convenient and less error-prone for a person submitting an answer.

Comment: that makes sense, my apologies, in times like these my ignorance gets the better of me. @klanomath

Answer (score 2):

Download and install [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/).

After downloading, you can remove the quarantine by entering the following command.

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads/gdisk-1.0.4.pkg
```

Enter the commands given below.

```
sudo gdisk /dev/disk0
t
2
af0a
w
y
```

You can also use the `gpt` command, but `gdisk` has the advantage of being atomic. In other words, no changes are made to the GPT until you enter the `y` command.

If you want to try using the `gpt` command without first booting to macOS Recovery, then here are the commands. I warn you this might cause the computer to hang.

```
sudo -f gpt remove -i 2 disk0
sudo -f gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 1796865488 -t apfs disk0
```

Comment: @ArtoriusCastus: Well so much go getting it right the first time. I made a mistake. You entered `af00` and you should have entered `af0a`. Sorry, you will have to do it again.

Comment: no big deal @DavidAnderson it was my fault for not c&p(ing) to begin with.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes, the af0a made the difference. Using

``sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0`` does allow the deleted linux partition to rejoin the larger disk0s2.

All without the need to restart my computer. But I will still test the recovery mode method regardless of this successful result

Comment: I appreciate you both walking on tightrope with me, @klanomath and David Anderson

Comment: The gpt command was not needed in my case, after using gdisk and changing af00 to af0a and verifying the whole thing. The command ``sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0`` immediately works and my drive was properly resized. Restarting was not an issue

Comment: From past experience, I would assume the `sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3` caused the problem. So with the problem fixed, you should have been able to enter the `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` successfully. In other words, `diskutil` can mess up when the partition type is `0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4` (i.e. linux).

Comment: yes, I believe that was where the problem arose, it seems that the 
``sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3`` command and the ``sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3`` are still somewhat volatile and not exactly stable even in newer versions of macOS (catalina 10.15.2 in this case).
It may work in one case, but not in others even if that instance is on the exact same device it worked on before. But that's just a theory of mine based on my experience doing it.

Comment: @klanomath: As for your now deleted comment: *Did you test the last two commands? I would say "a risky tightrope walk"... ;-)*. I did test on a sparse disk image. I do not know what would have happened, if the OP actually used the `gpt` commands posted in my answer. I was trying to post possible solutions that did not require rebooting (i.e. turning off my MacBook). If the computer hung, then the OP would have needed macOS Recovery to fix the computer.

Comment: I'll be testing that method after I reinstall Linux just to see what happens. Worst case scenario I'll have to solve the issue in recovery mode. @DavidAnderson

Comment: @DavidAnderson I think the reason why Artorius asked for a solution without reboot were probably unsubstantiated worries to lose all data. IMHO it's less risky to make a backup first and then execute either the gdisk command or the gpt commands. Then reboot and verifyDisk/verifyVolume and expand disk0s2.

Comment: Your humble opinion is exactly correct. I made a backup first prior attempting anything, but I'll still be testing both methods just for the hell of it @klanomath . Although i'll still be attempting to reboot and verify the drive, do everything via recovery mode.

Comment: I/we don't know all previous commands Arturo executed to create/remove the Linux partition or later to repair the mess. But I think he didn't really touch/manipulate disk0s2 in a unrecoverable way (= only the partition type got changed somehow). Considering all this I personally would always choose the Internet Recovery Mode/an external boot volume to manipulate disk0/disk0s2 and verify the disk/volumes later in such cases.

Comment: If i were to do this all via Internet recovery mode, do you have an overview of steps I could take @klanomath . I'll also put a description of exactly what i did because you are correct to say that i did not manipulate the disk0s2 in any strange manner.

Comment: @ArtoriusCastus In recovery mode it's simply `gpt -r show disk0` to get the partition sizes, then the two gpt commands (without `sudo` and the `-f` option) of David's answer. Then `diskutil verifyDisk disk0` and `diskutil verifyVolume [apfs_container_scheme_disk]` (alternatively it's `diskutil verifyDisk [apfs_container_scheme_disk]` - I always forget which one to use for the apfs_container_scheme_disk.)

Comment: There is this question from a few day ago: [How to uninstall Linux from a MacBook properly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380608/how-to-uninstall-linux-from-a-macbook-properly) I should note that the `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` command does to a `fsck_apfs` on `disk0s2` to verify the APFS container before resizing.

Comment: I'll be testing all these methods by reinstalling linux and seeing what happens. I'll drop a status report afterwards @klanomath

Comment: The order of the command is off is all @DavidAnderson ``sudo gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0`` works tried. I did not cause my macbook to hang.